# Suggested tags should take into account other tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-tags

I just asked [a C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27705913/3160466). When I got to tagging it, I had already put the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag in, and I added the [html-agility-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-agility-pack) tag. However, the system then went on to suggest the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag!

This is a bit of a problem as it encourages bad tagging in new users who think 'suggested tag' means 'put every possible association of this tag in'. This could lead to questions turning up in the wrong places, like, for example, this C# question turning up in the Java section.

I propose that the suggested tags should take into account other tags already put in. For example, if the C# tag is in, **no other language tags** should be suggested. Instead, perhaps language **associations** could be put in ([.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) for C#, for example). It might even be an idea that if no language tag is put in, the suggested tags could take into account the bracing style - C# and Java are similar, but because of this should be braced differently:

Java bracing:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {
    // code goes here
}
```

C# bracing:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Comment: If the system is going to check on coding-style I also want a new flag option: *Improper bracing used*. Let the war begin...

Comment: Coding style is preferential though. I can't imagine any scenario when trying to base things off of coding *style* would ever result in good predictions. FWIW, the suggested tags are [based purely off of keywords within your post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229018).

Comment: @animuson True. Still, it could take into account existing tags.

Comment: Also, I would expect it not to suggest a tag already present in the tag list. #oldestbugonthesite